# How to Put a Right-Click Context Menu on the Mat-tab-group component

Tags: angular, mat-tab

I am trying to implement a context menu pop up with a right click from the user.

Here is an existing implementation with a mat-tab-list:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-context-menu?file=app%2Fcontext-menu-example.html
I am trying to implement the same functionality but with a mat-tab-group component instead, here is a mat-tab-group example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-closing-example?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html
Anyone with Angular and Mat-tab-group experience know how to incorporate the context menu functionality into a mat-tab-group component?

Answer (score 0):

Miya, material angular has change from the code of the stackblitz. Now you need a "div" that was the `MatMenuTrigger`

You can read, e.g. this [link](https://marco.dev/angular-right-click-menu)

The idea is use a "div" fixed

```
<div [ngStyle]="{position:'fixed',
     top:contextMenuPosition.y,
     left:contextMenuPosition.x}" 
     [matMenuTriggerFor]="contextMenu"></div>
```

Now your tabs can have a ng-template mat-tab-label like

```
 <ng-template mat-tab-label>
    <div class="col" style="margin-left: 20px" 
        (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, {index:index})"
    >
      {{tab.name}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
```

See that you pass as "second argument" an object with the properties you need -In the e.g. I use the index of the tab-

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-tabs-closing-example-rudrgj?file=app%2Ftab-group-basic-example.html)